# Authenticating a user using a Django REST API

Tags: android, django, api, rest, authentication

What's the best way to authenticate a user using a Django REST API?

1) send the username/password encrypted in each request
2) get a session cookie

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to accept more answers to your previous questions. It gives people an incentive to help out more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session cookie is normally best way. or if you are feeling fancy you can try oauth.